# Поиск закономерности в последовательности чисел

Tags: алгоритм, delphi-7, delphi

Имеется много чисел, все они распределены от 0 до 12. Как написать программу на delphi-7 для выявления формулы, алгоритма, закономерности в последовательности чисел, по которой можно найти оставшиеся числа, подчиняющиеся этой закономерности?
Числа вводятся с клавиатуры до тех пор, пока не определится закономерность последовательности чисел. И выводится в текст следующее число.

Comment: Это уже попахивает созданием искусственного интеллекта.

P.S А вообще, насколько я знаю, генерация псевдослучайного числа - это сложный вычислительный процесс, который производится спецификация ми процессора. Так, Intel для этого создавало чипсет:

http://habrahabr.ru/post/128666/

Comment: Неа, это попахивает несданной лабой с привкусом сессии :-)

Comment: @den555, решили выиграть в рулетку ?

Comment: Например, [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Comment: Вот, меняют текст вопроса (0 - 36 заменили не 0 - 12) и комментарий становится дурацким, а отредактировать его уже нельзя (это к @ХэшКод).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обещем случае - никак. Абсолютно никак.
Но можно попытаться угадать алгоритм из сущестующих.

- методо первый. предположим, что числа подчиняются какой то формуле, например n * a % b (где процент - взятие по модулю). По ходу ввода чисел пытаемся подобрать коеффициенты. Если для какой то из формул удается - значит нашли. Недостаток - нужно держать базу формул.
- метод второй. Графический. Банально строим график по данным числам, по оси Х откладываем порядковый номер. Смотрим на график, при определенной сноровке можно угадать зависимость. Потом подобрать формулу целенаправеленно.
- метод третий. График строим на плоскости, используя пары чисел, как координаты x,y или тройки чисел, тогда третье число - цвет точки. Смотрим на результат. У некоторых, не очень хороших генераторов, сразу видны "узоры". Исходя из этого, можно угадать координаты точек.

Comment: Второй метод не проще первого. Надо иметь базу графиков?))))

Comment: Да, на график должен смотреть человек-математик.

Comment: -- Есть ли в паскале рандом?<br/>
-- 7.

Раз класс функций не указан, без ограничения общности можно выдавать следующее число с любого шага, притом любое.